# cPanel Git Version Control automatic deployment for cloned repositories

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, bitbucket, cpanel

after a bit of trouble I managed to set up a git version control in cPanel for a git repository.

Now I can update the website on the server by following these steps: log into cpanel, go into git version control section, select the repository, open pull or deploy tab and press "Update from Remote" button and then finally press "Deploy HEAD Commit" button.

Doing all this just add another unnecessary level of complexity to deploying our websites. That is why I looked into automatic deployment but from watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18tXFctuqQ0) tutorial is seems to only work on repositories created and hosted on cPanel and not on the cloned repositories.

The problem is that we host all of our git repositories on BitBucket.

So, is there any way to automatically deploy cloned repositories from BitBucket on Git Version Control?

Here is my .cpanel.yml

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    # NOTE: public_html on cPanel must not be removed or renamed.
    # This folder has owner USER:nobody, and the USER user does not have
    # access to change owner. So this folder must stay as-is to keep the nobody
    # group, which is critical to the site working. A new folder won't work.
    # test
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/CPANELuser/public_html/test/git-test
    - export REPOPATH='C:\Users\LOCALuser\Documents\Git\git-test'
    # Remove previous old files, if any.
    - /bin/rm -Rf ${DEPLOYPATH}_old
    # Copy old site files to another directory.
    - /bin/cp -R ${DEPLOYPATH} ${DEPLOYPATH}_old
    # Sync repository files to the deploy target path, excluding .git folder.
    # --delete-after will remove deleted files and folders after syncing.
    - /bin/rsync -aP --exclude '.git' --exclude '.well-known' ${REPOPATH}/ ${DEPLOYPATH} --delete-after
    # Set correct permissions.
    - /bin/chmod 755 ${DEPLOYPATH}
    - /bin/find ${DEPLOYPATH} -type d -exec /bin/chmod 755 '{}' \;
    - /bin/find ${DEPLOYPATH} -type f -exec /bin/chmod 644 '{}' \;
```